# Export data in CSV but with different columns set. Can it be done via a library?

Tags: python, csv, export

Data input:

```
[
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
    {'b': 2, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'a': 1},
    {'b': 2, 'd': 4, 'a': 1}
]
```

CVS output (columns order does not matter):

```
a, b, c, d, e
1, 2, 3
1, 2, ,  4, 5
1, 2, ,  4
```

Standard library [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module cannot cover such kind of input.

Is there some package or library for a single-method export?
Or a good solution to deal with column discrepancies?

Comment: Check out `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict().to_csv()`

You'll probably need to fill the blanks with `NaN`s or something but that would be my first intuition. Otherwise `xlwings` probably has some functionality for this but I've not really used it that much.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done fairly easily using the included `csv` module with a little preliminary processing.

```
import csv

data = [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
    {'b': 2, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'a': 1},
    {'b': 2, 'd': 4, 'a': 1}
]

fields = sorted(set.union(*(set(tuple(d.keys())) for d in data)))  # Determine columns.

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fields)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)

print('-fini-')
```

Contents of file produced:

```
a,b,c,d,e
1,2,3,,
1,2,,4,5
1,2,,4,
```

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
{'b': 2, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'a': 1},
{'b': 2, 'd': 4, 'a': 1}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df.to_csv(index=None))
```

Output:

```
a,b,c,d,e
1,2,3.0,,
1,2,,4.0,5.0
1,2,,4.0,
```

Comment: It seems it does the job. Why there is `.0`?

Comment: it's because pandas formats the cells as float. You can convert every cell to int with the following: `df = pd.DataFrame(lst).fillna(pd.NA).applymap(lambda x: x if pd.isna(x) else int(x))`

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass a restval argument to Dictwriter which is the default argument for missing keys in dictionaries

```
writer = Dictwriter(file, list('abcde'), restval='')
```

Comment: Yes, seem I missed it. But it still requires to mention all possible columns, doesn't it? `fieldnames=...`

Comment: yes, that is the second argument of DictWriter.

Comment: Please consider vote to reopen on [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73504010/grep-highlight-only-first-match-of-each-line-when-using-color) if you feel like!!